# two level joins in select query

Tags: mysql, php

i have 3 tables: `posts`, `tags` and `post_tags`

in post_tags i store post tags! and a post can have many tags

Now i want to select all tag names of post 1 while selecting post's own columns.

posts columns are: `id`, `title`
tags columns are: `id`, `name`
post_tags columns are: `id`, `post_id`, `tag_id`

---

I have reached up to here, but this returns only one tag name for post, not all tags: (any ideas ?)

```
select 
     p.*, t.name as tag_name 
from 
     posts p 
     inner join posts_tags pt on p.id = pt.post_id 
     inner join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id 
where 
     p.id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct, and should show as many tags as there are, in *different rows*. You can check it at [Rextester](http://rextester.com/PFMQED88808).

If you want all your tags to be converted into a single column (all tags concatened), and have just one row per post, you need to aggregate (`GROUP BY`) and use then [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Your query will look like (I've slightly changed the naming of your columns, for legibility):

```
-- All tags concat
SELECT
     p.post_id, p.post, group_concat(t.tag ORDER BY t.tag SEPARATOR ', ') AS all_tags
FROM 
     posts p 
     inner join posts_tags pt on p.post_id = pt.post_id 
     inner join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.tag_id 
WHERE 
     p.post_id = 1 
GROUP BY
     p.post_id, p.post ;
```

Check it [here](http://rextester.com/MEJSW98508)

---

**Addendum**

If you want not only `tags`, but something else, you can aggregate an expressions, and not just a column:

```
-- All tags, with id concat
SELECT
     p.post_id, p.post, 
     group_concat( concat(t.tag, ' [', t.tag_id, ']') ORDER BY t.tag SEPARATOR ', ') 
        AS all_tags_with_ids
FROM 
     posts p 
     inner join posts_tags pt on p.post_id = pt.post_id 
     inner join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.tag_id 
WHERE 
     p.post_id = 1 
GROUP BY
     p.post_id, p.post ;
```

Check it [here](http://rextester.com/FHR81653).

Comment: You don't have arrays in MySQL. But you can `group_concat` as shown in my answer.

Comment: You can `group_concat` an expression. See my extended answer.

Comment: Which version are you using? Rextester uses 5.7.something. And there, it works.

Comment: @MehdiAzmoudeh - "parse error"??  That is not the usual MySQL syntax error message.  What language are you going through?  Let's see your copy of the statement, plus a full copy of the error provided.